# How does helicopter mustering make financial sense?

Tags: helicopter, commercial-operations, economics, australia

I've seen and know that [helicopter mustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muster_(livestock)) is popular in Australia and what I do not understand is why this works from a business perspective.

Helicopters are expensive and dangerous machines so it does not seem cost effective to round up cattle and livestock when it could be done, not as quickly, by people on the ground with ATVs and other wheeled vehicles. Not to mention the low-level flying is very demanding and tough on the machines and maintenance.

Surely it would be cheaper to employ extra people than pay the expensive hourly rate of a helicopter?

Comment: Speaking of "things you wouldn't expect would be profitable to do by helicopter but are", apparently [helicopter-based cherry drying](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBe9GEhc7pE) is a thing that exists.

Comment: I suspect it comes down to terrain and distances .. Some of the large stations in the northern parts of australia are really large (like 10-20,000 sqkm) - https://www.entegra.com.au/anna-creek-the-biggest-cattle-station-in-australia/. Also the videos I've seen often have a water component in them / water buffalo - and that's going to be hard work at ground level ..

Comment: @MrR I can confirm, having done aerial mustering, that without a plane it could take a whole day just to locate the livestock in a paddock. Undulating terrain, trees, gullies make it difficult to quickly travel the distance on the ground.

Comment: "Surely it would be cheaper to employ extra people than pay the expensive hourly rate of a helicopter?"  Either you're wrong, or they're wrong, and it's their money they're spending.  Ergo, either they have money to piss away, or there's something you're missing.

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, that's why they're asking a question here. I'm not sure what the point of your comment is.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I suspect that Ron's point was that the statement "Surely it would be cheaper..." should really be "Surely I must be missing something...".

Comment: Could someone bring some factual information about how much it costs per hour (or perhaps "per muster") for a bush helicopter + pilot ?

Comment: If using helicopters for mustering is surprising, you might also be interested in how they're used to [harvest Christmas trees](https://verticalmag.com/news/helicopters-complete-oregon-christmas-tree-harvest/) and [dry fruit](https://blog.aopa.org/aopa/tag/cherry-drying/).

Comment: @user2705196 exactly.  "Surely it would be cheaper to employ extra people than pay the expensive hourly rate of a helicopter?" implicitly means that OP thinks that he knows more about the economics of helicopter usage than the people using the helicopters.

Answer (score 17):

Two reasons:

1. It is way faster and allows one person with a relatively cheap-to-run R-22 to do the work of several cowboys.  You're paying for the cowboy 24-7 if they are on staff, which is usually the case on a sprawling and remote ranch/station where you have to keep them on full time (and the horse if using them); you're only paying for the machine (direct hourly operating costs at least) while it's running.
2. It almost eliminates losses from stragglers that get missed and later become dinner for predators.  This feature was a welcome surprise when gyrocopters and helicopters were first tried out. Originally, gyrocopters were used to help out with the cowboys, mainly to hunt for strays that couldn't be seen from ground level. When the R22 came out, being able to hover and maneuver in confined areas, it became feasible to do both the mustering and overwatch role from the air.

Between the two, the business case starts to favour the helicopter.  If it didn't, they wouldn't do it. Granted, it is pretty dangerous flying, not for the faint of heart, but there are lots of young pilots keen for a thrill.

Comment: Your note about "paying for the cowboy 24-7" might not necessarily be clear if someone isn't familiar with exactly how isolated (and enormous) Aussie cattle stations can be. Perhaps add a bit more context to that?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz - Actually, it would be similar regardless of the area. Even in the US, the majority of cattle hands are either permanent, seasonal, temporary, or as needed. Very few will be paid hourly. This is a job without a punch clock. Maybe a time sheet can be used for part-timers and as-needed personnel. But, the hours can be so long and varied, that it would not make sense to pay per hour. On the other hand, an R-22 can be operated for $100-200 an hour, not including the pilot.

Comment: I recall when reading about Aussie helicopter mustering years ago that the savings from the reduction in losses from overlooked strays was surprisingly high and is really what clinched the business case.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't see how it's financially viable in most situations, but I'm guessing it's financially viable in a few situations or when shorthanded.

Although horses are expensive to "maintain", almost every ranch already has them.  Feed and medical are the two largest expenses, and you're going to be providing that whether or not you are using them for mustering/herding.  Horses fart and breathe, but besides that, they don't produce exhaust.  I'm guessing they produce methane, but I've never measured it myself.  They also produce manure that enriches the soil.  Their hooves help break up the soil, which allows grasses and plants to prosper.  Animals like horses, bison, and cattle are good the health of the land.

ATVs are inexpensive to fuel and somewhat inexpensive to maintain; they are not too expensive to purchase.  ATVs produce toxic exhaust.  Unlike horses, they compact the soil, which inhibits grasses and plants from growing.  Over time, ATVs can be bad for the land, but using them on the same tracks can significantly help reduce this degradation.

Helicopters are expensive to purchase (or rent) and time-consuming to properly maintain.  Fuel and maintenance costs will depend on the model.  Helicopters produce toxic exhaust.  Helicopters can cause loose soil to get moved, but this is usually not a problem, as the net effect is usually minimal.

There are two situation where I can see a helicopter being an advantage over horses and ATVs:

1. When you are shorthanded.  As the size the of the herd increases, and the size of the range increases, you need more cowgirls and cowbows on horses or ATVs to manage the task.  A helicopter could help in shorthanded situations.
2. When the range exceeds that which horses or ATVs can travel while having the feed/water or fuel they need.  For horses, this depends entirely on the breed, condition, and age of the horses and the breed, condition, and age of the herd.  If appropriate and sufficient food/water will not be available for the horses, but will be available for the herd, horses may not be viable.  I have never seen this happen, but I could create a contrived example to make it happen, and it's possible such real-world examples exist.  For ATVs, I think it's more obvious.

Meaning absolutely no disrespect to John K whatsoever, I will politely disagree with two of the reasons he posted:

1. Speed.  The limiting factor of moving a herd is typically the speed of the herd itself.  A helicopter does not move a herd faster (unless you are doing something inappropriate with the helicopter and causing the animals undue stress).
2. Stragglers.  Skilled ranchers don't leave stragglers.  Yes, mistakes can happen (such as an animal stuck in the brush and not being seen), but they are very rare, and a helicopter could make the same mistake.  Since a helicopter pilot cannot hear an animal crying, a calf calling its cow, or its cow responding,  I think the risk of stragglers would actually be greater with a helicopter.  It's possible a helicopter provides some sort of advantage here that I'm not thinking of, but I have never flown a helicopter for this purpose, so I am not personally aware of any.  A helicopter could sweep a large area after moving a herd, but I've always used fixed-wing aircraft for periodic sweeps of large areas, not a helicopter.

John did mention cost, and I wonder if this is a primary factor.  Cost will depend on many factors and variables, so we don't have a clear picture.  I can create theoretical situations where employing helicopters would be cost-efficient, and those in which they would not be.  But since there are at least a dozen different variables at play, it would really depend on the exact situation.

Comment: A lot is going to depend on terrain.  In open & fairly flat country, I can see how a helicopter might be useful.  Around here, where a lot of the open range grazing is small meadows interspersed with forested mountains, probably not useful at all.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, definitely.  In some terrain a helicopter would likely only represent a liability.  That said, I watched, with a little disbelief, this guy who trims massive trees using a crazy rig with huge swirling sawblades attached to his helicopter via a shaft.  Skilled genius, or a disaster waiting to happen... you decide!  (And history will eventually reveal.)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Those are awesome! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_saw One was used by the villains in a James Bond movie in the 1990s, IIRC.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, that is them!  Good find!  Now that you mention James Bond, I also have a faint recollection of one being used in one of those films or books... (3 minutes elapse...) I found it... The World is Not Enough (1999).  I don't know if the aerial saw they used in that movie was an industrial one, or a creation of their prop team (or even full/partial SFX), but that's the general crazy idea!  Here's a link to a clip from that movie featuring the aerial saw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aL1VF9zlfM

Comment: Hmm, a lot of the statements up top of this answer could be just wrong.  For example, i's really, really REALLY expensive to keep a string of horses, it's a deep infrastructure problem.  (A random example, it would be trivial to spend 100 grand a year *merely on the incidental issue of pickup trucks and trailers* to haul the horses around 100s of km.  Hence, "almost every ranch already has them" this is just wrong.  Horses are an incredibly expensive novelty, and the one and only reason to have them is for muster.

Comment: Something that strikes me as odd is your statement about toxic exhaust. Turbine helicopters would be expensive to own and operate. Most of the aircraft herding operations that I know of or have seen use piston aircraft. In which case, except for a slightly higher lead count, they will have a very similar carbon footprint to a couple of ATVs or one truck. Even turbine helicopters burn the equivalent of clean diesel. An R-22 can efficiently operate at less than a 10 GPH at 100 MPH fuel burn rate. A truck will operate at 10MPG at 100 MPH. Normal ATVs can not reach 100 MPH.

Comment: I met a guy at the last US Helicopter Safety Alliance Safety Stand-Down who owned a business that did helicopter underslung operations like rotary-saw tree trimming. In most s was done in areas that had to be trimmed for power lines on a regular bases in very hard to reach areas. There is always a cost-benefit analysis to these sorts of things to justify the risk and expense. Otherwise, it would not be done.

Comment: @Fattie: I have to disagree about horses being "an incredibly expensive novelty", 'cause I've been supporting a couple for the last decade or more.  They're not all that expensive, especially if you have adequate grazing.  You do have a point about the expense of hauling them long distances, but that depends on the area you're grazing.

Comment: hi @jamesqf for sure, I'm talking in the context of the question.   (to wit, the handful of ridiculously massive ranches on Earth, that (amazingly) use choppers for herding since (again, amazingly) it's cheaper.)  to operate the battalion of horses + cowboys needed for that (once a year project) is a huge operation at the scale of "buildings, entire staffs, etc".  Indeed!!!!  note that ranches of this scale that do use cowboys + horses to herd, of course just hire a specialized crew of cowboys + horses at that time of year

Comment: @Fattie: But those amazingly huge ranches are the exception, not the rule.  More reasonably-sized ranches do have the horses, and use them, especially in difficult terrain.

Comment: @jamesqf - yes - absolutely !  As I understand it, the question is about the 5 ranches in the far north of Australia, etc, where (amazingly) they use choppers.  Horses are the best !

Comment: @Fattie wrote "i's [sic] really, really REALLY expensive to keep a string of horses" and "Horses are an incredibly expensive novelty, and the one and only reason to have them is for muster". Those are odd things to say, as they are all incorrect.  Horses have dozens of uses on a ranch as well as many uses on a farm.  On most ranches, they are a requirement, not a luxury.  Ever try roping cattle from a helicopter?  How about moving massive bulls with a little ATV?  Good luck partner, and I hope you have a good hospital nearby!

Comment: @DeanF. wrote "Something that strikes me as odd is your statement about toxic exhaust."  I was simply being comprehensive, and those were just a few words in a long answer.  It's all about tradeoffs, values, and pride.  Some ranches pride themselves in not using any combustion engines for labor, but most do.  Regardless, it's important to be aware of the impact of our decisions when we choose to use devices that emit toxins and be aware of alternative that do not.  That said, sometimes the alternatives have their downsides, which is why I mentioned that horses likely produce methane.

Comment: @DeanF. wrote "An R-22 can efficiently operate at less than a 10 GPH at 100 MPH fuel burn rate. A truck will operate at 10MPG at 100 MPH. Normal ATVs can not reach 100 MPH."  If you're trying to drive a herd at 100MPH, you're doing it wrong.  Either that, or you are are herding unusually fast coalitions of long-range cheetahs. ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - You do realize how popular fast food is here in the US. Don’t you? . My point was that fuel consumption and carbon footprint were similar. I used a convenient universal measurement for comparison.

Comment: @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket: You don't use the 100 mph of your helicopter, or FTM whatever top speed your truck, ATV, or horse can manage, to drive the cattle in a straight line.  You use it to circle outside & behind the herd to keep it moving in the direction you want.  You really don't want the cattle moving at more than walking speed, as they lose weight from the exercise.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, that is what I was saying.